# Can't make button color change

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

Trying to do something super basic which doesn't seem to work:

**HTML**

```
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>        
    <button style="margin: 10px; color:white; background-color: #4CAF50; font-size:40px;" type="button" id="aaa" > גבע</button>    
</body>
```

**JS**

```
$("aaa").click(function () {
    $(this).css('backgroundcolor', 'white');
});
```

The button color doesn't seem to change. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: `$("#aaa")`, prefix `#` for [ID Selector](https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/)

Comment: #aaa not aaa  missing  # for id?

Comment: You don't need jQuery UI for that. JQuery alone is enough. In fact, you can even change the button color in plain old javascript

Comment: I have resolved your bugs please check my comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two bugs are there

1. Put `#` before the id selector which is missing in your code.
2. The CSS(or DOM style) property should be `background-color` or `backgroundColor`

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button style="margin: 10px; color:white; background-color: #4CAF50; font-size:40px;" type="button" id="aaa" > גבע</button>

<script>

    $("#aaa").click(function () {
        $(this).css('background-color', 'white');
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('.thing').on('click', function() {
  $(this).css('background', 'red');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class='thing'>button</button>
```

`$('#aaa')`

You need to target the element by id in your case.

Answer (score 1):

Two changes required

1. Id selection need a `#` in jquery
2. change  `backgroundColor` to `backgroundColor` or `background-color`

```js
$("#aaa").click(function() {
  $(this).css('backgroundColor', 'white');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button style="margin: 10px; color:white; background-color: #4CAF50; font-size:40px;" type="button" id="aaa"> גבע</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

`button` is an id selector `#aaa`.

```html
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>


<button style="margin: 10px; color:white; background-color: #4CAF50; font-size:40px;" type="button" id="aaa" > גבע</button>

<script>

    $("#aaa").click(function () {
    
        $(this).css('background-color', 'white');
    });

</script>
</body>

</html>
```

```
<script>

    $("#aaa").click(function () {
        $(this).css('background-color', 'white');
    });

</script>
```

Comment: `$("aaa")` selects all `<aaa>` elements, which are none

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with:

```
$("#aaa").click(function () {
        $(this).css('backgroundColor', 'white');
    });
```

There is a problem with your selector rule, you are missing **"#"**

Answer (score 0):

For id use `#` for class use `.` in selector

```
 $("#aaa").click(function () {
    $(this).css({'background-color':'white'});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).css("background-color", "yellow");
```

replace `"backgroundcolor"` attribute to `"background-color"`

Then it will work!

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

> 1) Change `$("aaa")` To `$("#aaa")` : 
>   **For `id` selector must use `#` sign.**
>
> 2)Change `backgroundcolor` To `background-color`

```js
$("#aaa").click(function () {
  $(this).css('background-color', 'white');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button style="margin: 10px; color:white;background-color: #4CAF50;  font-size:40px;" type="button" id="aaa" > גבע</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

for id use '#' and for 'backgroundcolor' use 'background-color'

```
$("#aaa").click(function () {
    $(this).css('background-color', 'white');
});
```